# Can anyone identify the instrument that James Morrison is playing in this picture?

Tags: instruments, brass

From the bell flare it looks like it might be some sort of flugel horn. Can anyone say for definite what it is?

[image]

Comment: The source of the photo might be helpful.

Comment: Australian trumpet..?

Comment: Voting to close, as an identification question.

Comment: I don't know much about brass, but seems like it could be a rotary-valve flugelhorn.

Comment: @Theodore The flare is kinda borderline between flugelhorn and cornet, to my eyes. On the flugelhorn side, looks like the mouth pipe goes right into valve one. Cornet mouth pipes usually go through a tuning slide first and then into valve three.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the proportions of the instrument it can only be a flugelhorn. Morrison has his instruments custom made by [Schlagerl](https://schagerl.com). They built a bass trumpet for him in a very similar form ([source](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/81838918205281070/)):
[image]

Comment: Good find! Started exploring Schlagerl website also but gave up...